# How to style label attributes in Flex forms?

Tags: apache-flex, forms, coding-style, label, flash-builder

I've got FormItems with labels, and I'd like for the label to appear on top of the textinput within it rather than to its left, but I don't know where I need to go or what CSS I need to set this.

```
<mx:Form id="myform" defaultButton="{BtnSave}">
  <mx:FormItem label="MyData" required="true">
    <s:TextInput id="dataTextInput" text="{data}"/>
  </mx:FormItem>
</mx:Form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is possible w/ MX Forms.  I guess in theory you could do something like this:

```
<mx:Form id="myform" defaultButton="{BtnSave}">
  <mx:FormItem required="true" direction="vertical">
    <s:Label text="MyData" />
    <s:TextInput id="dataTextInput" text="{data}"/>
  </mx:FormItem>
</mx:Form>
```

But, If you're going to do that then why bother using the form in the first place?